# Помогите пожалуйста написать скрипт на Vue js для показа изображений

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js

**Дано задание:** 
реализуйте альбом изображений используя vue.js + bootstrap + css3. То есть конкретных требований нет. Но при этом показ изображений должен быть сопровожден анимацией.
В разметке есть div с миниатюрами и ссылками на их полноразмерные копии. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на миниатюру открывалось изображение с возможностью переключится на следующее не закрывая его. Вот пример моей разметки.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="./img/big/01.jpg" class="photo"><img src="./img/small/01.jpg" alt="image1" width="150" height="100"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать что то типа fancybox например. Или любую другую  реализацию слайдера, которая уже описана как компонент для vuejs.
Как именно использовать - описано в документации компонента. 
Вот страница с набором слайдеров - выбирайте на любой вкус

https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/slider/

Честно говоря не очень понял зачем вы привели пример своей разметки, однако надеюсь не потому что вы даже не открывали документацию к VueJS :)